# Why is this function being called (python switch function for user input)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, switch-statement, user-input

I'm new to python and trying to set up a command line program that runs a few different commands based on user input. User input will be sent to a function with a dictionary of different functions. My code so far looks like this: `

## Functions for the different command options

```
def quit():
   print("youre quiting")
   ender = False

def ls():
   print("You're listing files!")
```

## Dictionary mapping input to command functions

```
 def commands(argument):
   switcher = {
      "quit": quit(),
      "ls": ls(),
      3: "you typed 3",
   }
   return switcher.get(argument, "Invalid command")
```

## Main command loop: Takes user input, checks how many arguments are entered and calls the appropriate command function

```
while ender == True:

userIn = input("okay go:")
userSplit = userIn.split()
numArgs = len(userSplit)

if numArgs == 0:
    print("You must enter a command! Use the command 'help' for more information.")
elif numArgs >= 2:
    print("You entered too many arguments! Use the command 'help for more information.")
else:
    print(commands(userSplit[0])
```

No matter what I input, it calls both the ls and quit functions and prints their statements. However if I type an invalid command that works and tells me its invalid (in addition to calling those two functions).

What's going on here? How can I get it to call only the function I enter? Thanks for your time.

Comment: In order to populate your `switcher` dictionary the interpreter has to execute those functions.

Comment: They get called because you call them. Simply don't.

Comment: So how would I only call them after user input? Do I just need to use a big if else block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`quit()`, eg. invokes the function **then** and stores the *resulting value* as the dictionary value. Just store the function *without* first  calling it:

```
switcher = {
  "quit": quit,
  "ls": ls,
  "3": lambda: print("You typed 3!")
}
fn = switcher[cmd]
fn() # now call the selected function
```

Make all the values functions/lambdas for uniformity of invocation, and use *strings* for all keys so they will be found.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't really understand the use of the lambda until this, python is starting to make more sense to me now.

Comment: This solves the issue of your functions - but your implementation of "quit" is not going to work as is, because the variable "ender" inside your quit method is local to the function - is not going to change the value of "ender" variable in your execution.

Answer (score 2):

When you are constructing the dictionary you are invoking `ls()` instead of assigning the key "ls" to a reference of `def ls()`.

Therefore, every time you invoke `commands()` the dictionary is constructed and both `quit()` and `ls()` are invoked. Your dictionary at runtime becomes

```
{
  "ls": None, 
  "quit": None,
}
```

```py
def test(argument):
    def ls():
        print("you're listing")

    def lsCorrect():
        print("you're listing from a function reference")

    switcher = {
        "ls": ls(),
        "lsCorrect": lsCorrect,
    }
    return switcher.get(argument, "default")


print('first call')
# switcher[lsCorrect] => reference to lsCorrect, so we then invoke it with ()
test("lsCorrect")()
try:
    print('second call')
    # when constructing the dictionary ls() is invoked and that function returns None
    # so we get a TypeError trying to call a function on None
    test("ls")()
except TypeError:
    print('tried to invoke something thats not a function')
```